# How to solve this problem in vmware workstation pro 14

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

[VMWARE workstation pro 14 can't install because of it's ended prematurely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6iJy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens if you have outdated OS or you have older/not have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistribute. So to solve this you need to install/update your Visual C++ 2015 and then update your windows.

Secondly when you try to install it run the msi/installer as Administrator.

Hope this should solve your problem.